# How do I export and use a function created inside App.js in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have created a hook that hold the authentication state of the user. When user has logged in I want to update this state, I have created a function inside App.js, how do I  use this function inside my login screen to update the hook and then send user to the home screen.

I need to use updateAuth inside my login screen and pass true to it, how do it do this

```
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").then((val) =>
    val == "true" ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false)
  );

  function updateAuth(value) {
    value ? setIsAuthenticated(value) : null;
  }

    return isAuthenticated ? (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={Product} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    ) : (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
```

1. List item

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `initialParams` prop.

[Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

```js
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} initalParams={{isAuthenticated}} />
```